# Create interactive HTML banners for Google AdWords using Google web designer

Tags: google-ads-api

after searching  a lot decided to post question here hoping to get any solution.

What I have to do:
I have to make interactive banners for Google Adwords platform, shortly to describe it consists of two parts, on the 1st part appears spidometer and alarms signs within green button where user has to click and after clicking there is 2nd part where is displayed text and only than user should be redirected to the site. Here is a non accurate example what we have done using Google web designer: http://example.ge/test/

Problem:

When uploading this banner in Google Adwords it links whole banner 1st and 2nd step with destination URL and the main idea is lost to send customer to the landing page after he sees 2nd slide. We need to link only 2nd step after clicking green button appeared text.

If you have any questions for more detailes I would be more than happy to provide.

Do you know any solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Google Web Designer, but if you use the `extiapi.js` functionality, this should be possible.

Just include it in your creative:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/pagead/gadgets/html5/api/exitapi.js"> </script>
```

And then call the `ExitApi.exit()` function on the second click.

Comment: Actually we want adwords banner to be not clickable, we want to block adwords final destination URL, like do not have a tag on image tag.

Comment: In that case, it's not possible. But why would you even want to have a non-clickable banner...?

Comment: Look, we have a creative campaign pf car fixing company, this banner from the beginning look like a spidometer and all the alarms are red , like car has all technician problems and there is green button, clicking on it customer should not be sent on the landing page since there is also second part of the banner like slider, clicking on the 1st slider user must be sent on 2nd slider and after clicking on 2nd slider to the landing page.

Comment: Green Burton solves all problems and than they must see this second slider because there is info and logo

Comment: But then after the second click, you do want people to go to the destination URL? So your banner *is* clickable after all?

Comment: Yes, in the end he should be redirected to the site

Comment: Then you can use `ExitApi.exit()`.